# ¿Cómo se usa el Symbol()? (tengo ejemplo que me confunde)

Tags: javascript

estoy aprendiendo sobre js, y me aparece un tema sobre tipo de dato primitivo Symbol. Según el material es inmutable y no se puede modificar. Pero cuando intento usarlo me deja modificarlo. Por lo que no entiendo que estoy haciendo mal. Paso el ejemplo para que me puedan ayudar:

```js
const id = Symbol('uno');
var obj = {
 [id]: 123456
}
console.log(obj); // {Symbol(uno): 123456}
obj[id] = 100; //lo modifica al valor
console.log(obj); // {Symbol(uno): 100}
```

Comment: No pude reproducir tu ejemplo, pero en ningún momento estás modificando el símbolo, sino la propiedad del objeto que tiene ese símbolo como clave.